# Send woocommerce emails to user email not to billing email

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to send e-mails to user account email and not to billing email in WooCommerce.

I only found that code but I think this is outdated and I also don't want to send 2 mails only one to customer user email.

Code here:

https://www.webdesign101.net/send-e-mails-user-account-email-billing-email-woocommerce/

Tried this code but outdated and also 2 mails instead of one going to user email.

And I didn't found the line in woocommerce/templates/email to change the header from `billing_email` to `user_email`.

I want so **send emails from WooCommerce to user email not to billing email**.

Answer (score 0):

```
function wc_change_new_order_email_recipient($recipient, $order) {
        global $woocommerce;
        $user = $order->get_user();
        $recipient[] = $user->user_email;

        return $recipient;
    }

    add_filter('woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'wc_change_new_order_email_recipient', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i will test it ;)

Comment: hi, i copied the code into my functions.php of my childtheme but now there are no emails going throug at all.