# Avoid WooCommerce new order notification for specific product exclusively

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, email-notifications

Following  this code example [Disable WooCommerce email notification for specific product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43292048/disable-woocommerce-email-notification-for-specific-product) *(I can't post comment there yet)*. I implemented the code to run for isolated product, I mean only if the product  is in the order *(`$product_id == 5274`)*, this code works:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'remove_free_course_notifications', 10, 2);
function remove_free_course_notifications( $recipient, $order )
{
    $page = $_GET['page'] = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : '';
    if ('wc-settings' === $page) {
        return $recipient;
    }

    if (!$order instanceof WC_Order) {
        return $recipient;
    }
    //my product id is 5274 
    $items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $product_id = $item['product_id'];
        if ($product_id == 5274) {
            $recipient = '';
        }
        return $recipient;
    }
}
```

But if a the order has other items (products) at the same time there is no notification sent to the admin.

Please can you let me know how to change this code to send the admin notification for the rest of items included in the order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is a bit obsolete. Use the following instead, to stop new order admin notification for an "exclusive" defined product:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'remove_free_course_notifications', 10, 2 );
function remove_free_course_notifications( $recipient, $order )
{
    if ( ! is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) {
        return $recipient;
    }

    $targeted_product_id = 5274; // Here set your product ID
    $other_found = $product_found = false;

    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
        if ( $item->get_product_id() == $targeted_product_id ) {
            $product_found = true;
        } else {
            $other_found = true;
        }
    }
    
    if ( $product_found && ! $other_found ) {
        return '';
    }

    return $recipient;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

Comment: You can also use the `woocommerce_email_enabled_new_order` filter to return Boolean `false` whenever you need to disable the email notificaiton.